# There are other shape properties scale-rotation invariant except HuMoment?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, scikit-image

Which is the difference between WeightedNormalizedMoments, WeightedHuMoments and HuMoments? (http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.6/api/skimage.measure.html)

There are other shape properties scale-rotation invariant except HuMoment? There are example that show me how can i implement them? I find this example in c++ [OpenCV(C): calculating moments FROM contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675878/opencvc-calculating-moments-from-contour) but i prefer working in python

Comment: There is a very trivial descriptor that is invariant to everything: number of connected components; question solved ? But that is hardly a good descriptor per se, so maybe you want something better than that ? Fourier descriptors can be easily made invariant to scale and rotation, question solved now ? One of the problems with your question is that it actually contains multiple questions, pick one of them to be your question.

Answer (score 2):

Moments are always calculated/summed over a local image feature, which needs to be segmented and labelled in the first place. The following formula is valid for the weighted and non-weighted case:

```
m_ji = sum{ array(x, y) * x^j * y^i }
```

The actual difference between weighted and non-weighted moments in scikit-image (and in general) is the following:

```
non-weighted:  array(x, y) is a binary image
weighted:      array(x, y) is a grey-level image (each point/pixel is weighted by its grey-level)
```

These moments are only translation-invariant. To make them scale-invariant we need to normalize them with the following formula:

```
nu_ji = mu_ji / m_00^[(i+j)/2 + 1]
```

Invariance is meant in terms of geometric transformation.

For more information about moments and its applications you can also have a look at the linked references in the `skimage.measure.regionprops` function.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that you need is written here, including the definition of how to calculate your own moments. It's a trivial and sub-100 lines of code implementation.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment

Of course, you only want to sum over pixels actually inside the contour, so PointPolygonTest will be of use to you.

Comment: i'm not well explained, here i find http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html these 3 differents moments: WeightedNormalizedMoments, WeightedHuMoments and HuMoments. On wikipedia there are only mathematical formula.  how i use it: skimage.measure.regionprops(label_image, properties=['huMoments']) ? labelimage is image's name?

Comment: and WeightedHuMoments, why ought to be weighted?

Comment: i find it for cv2 module here. http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/contours-3-extraction.html there is a function moments for finding centroid.